# Save variable between loops in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, serial

I have this code:

```
int data=0;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
    Serial.write(data);
    delay(50);
}

void serialEvent() {
    data = Serial.read();
}
```

This example should update the data variable when serial data is received. But for some reason it does not work that way, nothing gets printed in the serial monitor.

But when I move the `Write` method to `serialEvent` function, I have my data printed as expected.  Why is this happening? If I'm correct, the `data` variable should be printed with the last value I got from `Serial.read()`.

Comment: Just FYI. There is now a stack dedicated to Arduino http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: And another one about programming... stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Kamil  On average, the folks at Arduino.SE are more versed in Arduino code than the folks on SO or here on EE.SE.

Comment: Agreed. People on SO are more likely to complain about a missing `main()` than be of actual use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler sees that you read `data` each time through the loop, but never update it anywhere that can be directly reached. It therefore has optimized the code such that the initial value of `data` (0) is used instead of reading the actual value.

You can disable this optimization by declaring the variable `volatile`. This will force the compiler to generate code that reads the actual value each time instead.

```
volatile int data=0;
```

Comment: It would be very interesting to see a spelled-out explanation of why the compiler doesn't know that the data variable referenced in serialEvent() is intended to be the same one referenced in the outer context... and why volatile fixes that. (Though I suspect we get further into arduino-specific territory there.)

Comment: It's not so much that the compiler doesn't know that they're the same, it's that the compiler doesn't realize that `serialEvent()` will be called asynchronously. It's exactly the same thing as, say, Linux kernel code and system calls. Could that be fixed by causing `ISR()` to disable that sort of optimization? Sure, but not without *much* more work than just telling the compiler to not optimize via `volatile`.

Comment: I would buy your line of argument if serialEvent() was called from an ISR. However, it appears to be called from the main loop.